# SQL Error: ORA-01422: "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having a hard time understanding what's wrong with my SQL-script.
I get following error message:

> Fehlerbericht -
>   ORA-01422: Exakter Abruf gibt mehr als die angeforderte Zeilenzahl zurück
>
> ORA-06512: in Zeile 58
>
> > 1422. 00000 - "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>
> *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>
> *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

The Script:

```
DECLARE
    obj_exists           NUMBER (38, 0);
    faqqestion           VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE);
    targetobjid          NUMBER (38, 0);
    translatedtemplate   BOOLEAN;
BEGIN                                                         -- prints header
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (
           '"'
        || 'TemplateID'
        || '";"'
        || 'Templatetext'
        || '";"'
        || 'Sprache'
        || '";');

    -- iterates over the latest version of all 'de' templates
    FOR latestgermanobjects
        IN (  SELECT vs.sl_vs_id       vsId,
                     vs.sl_obj_id      vsObjId,
                     TRANSM.sl_obj_id  transmObjId,
                     TRANSM.lang,
                     OBJ.sl_obj_id     objObjId,
                     faq.faq_template_id faqTemplateId
                FROM sl_versionset vs
                     INNER JOIN sl_pp01_trans_meta transM
                         ON VS.sl_obj_id = TRANSM.sl_obj_id
                     INNER JOIN sl_pp01_obj obj
                         ON TRANSM.sl_obj_id = OBJ.sl_obj_id
                     INNER JOIN sl_pp01_faq01 faq
                         ON OBJ.sl_obj_id = FAQ.sl_obj_id
               WHERE     VS.sl_vs_next IS NULL
                     AND VS.sl_vs_deleted_flag = 0
                     AND VS.sl_vs_state <> 'Deprecated'
                     AND transm.lang = 'de'
                     AND obj.sl_obj_objtyp_id IN (334)
                     AND obj.sl_obj_deleted_flag = 0
            ORDER BY faq.faq_template_id ASC)
    LOOP
        -- iterate over all languages except 'de' to check translation
        FOR singlelanguagecursor
            IN (SELECT sl_metaval_varchar
                  FROM slma_meta_values
                 WHERE sl_metaval_varchar <> 'de' AND slma_metatype_id = 5)
        LOOP
            translatedtemplate := FALSE;

            -- iterate over all versions of versionset of the german template to find old tranlsations
            FOR templates
                IN (  SELECT sl_obj_id
                        FROM sl_versionset
                       WHERE     sl_vs_id = latestgermanobjects.vsid
                             AND sl_vs_deleted_flag = 0
                    ORDER BY sl_obj_id DESC)
            LOOP
                SELECT COUNT (1)
                  INTO obj_exists
                  FROM sl_pp01_trans_meta
                 WHERE     source_io = templates.sl_obj_id
                       AND lang = singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar;

                -- checks, if a translation of the chosen language exists
                IF obj_exists >= 1
                THEN
                    translatedtemplate := TRUE;

                    -- if only a tranlsation of a older version of the source object exists
                    IF templates.sl_obj_id <> latestgermanobjects.objobjid
                    THEN
                        SELECT sl_obj_id
                          INTO targetobjid
                          FROM sl_pp01_trans_meta
                         WHERE     source_io = templates.sl_obj_id
                               AND lang =
                                       singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar;

                        SELECT faq_question
                          INTO faqqestion
                          FROM sl_pp01_templ01
                         WHERE sl_obj_id = targetobjid;

                        -- prints 'Template Id', tranlsation of templatetext, language of translation of a transation of a older source object
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (
                               '"'
                            || latestgermanobjects.faqtemplateid
                            || '";"'
                            || faqqestion
                            || '";"'
                            || singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar
                            || '";');
                    END IF;

                    -- ends loop, after translation has found
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;

            -- if no translation is available
            IF NOT translatedtemplate
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line (
                       '"'
                    || latestgermanobjects.faqtemplateid
                    || '";"'
                    || 'translation n/a'
                    || '";"'
                    || singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar
                    || '";');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

New to SQL and PL/SQL so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your SQL "SELECT sl_obj_id 
                INTO   targetobjid 
                FROM   sl_pp01_trans_meta 
                WHERE  source_io = templates.sl_obj_id 
                       AND lang = singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar; " returns more than ONE row. It should only return ONE row because of the "INTO" clause.

Comment: By the way, `select xxx into vvv` returns an error if there is no result. You should make these queries inside cursors and use them. Your code will be more readable too.

Comment: thanks both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some example-explaination-code for your error:

```
declare
    v_text   VARCHAR2(4000);
begin

    -- this will work fine..
    SELECT * INTO v_text FROM
    ( -- this is a fake-table
        SELECT 'some text' FROM DUAL
    );

    dbms_output.put_line(v_text); 

    -- this will get you an no data found exception
    BEGIN

        SELECT * INTO v_text FROM
        ( -- this is a fake-table
            SELECT 'some text' FROM DUAL
        )
        WHERE 1 = 2;

        dbms_output.put_line(v_text);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('there is no data..');
    END;

    -- this will get you your exception 'too many rows'
    BEGIN

        SELECT * INTO v_text FROM
        ( -- this is a fake-table
            SELECT 'some text' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 'some text' FROM DUAL
        );

        dbms_output.put_line(v_text);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('there is too much data..');
    END;

end;
```

Your specific problem is row 69, i guess:

```
SELECT sl_obj_id
  INTO targetobjid
  FROM sl_pp01_trans_meta
 WHERE     source_io = templates.sl_obj_id
       AND lang =
               singlelanguagecursor.sl_metaval_varchar;
```

If you get more than one row, your `INTO` is not allowed. Fix your select (`WHERE ROWNUM = 1` **!!!Use only if result is correct!!!**) or handle the exception.